# Web page with upload/download speed for a user

Tags: performance, bandwidth

I want to make an URL that can be sent to the user. When he follows that URL, he'll get a page displaying upload/download speed for that user to the server the page is hosted on. Basically, I want to host my own speedtest. It'll be used for troubleshooting so fast to implement but dirty is better than neat and proper solution.

On the server I've got PHP, perl, python, apache and nginx and can use any of them. In what direction should I look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using speedtest. It allows to embed the speed tracker into your page.

Answer (score 0):

I never like those speedtests, because they don't really represent your bandwidth accurately at all. Used to live in a university dorm with 100 MBit, and the pipe would indeed give me in excess of 90 MBit if properly utilized. But the speedtests would return no more than 15 MBit ever. Part of the problem is that web tests (a) don't do multiconnection tests, (b) run into various bottlenecks such as their own servers, their ISPs, or their TCP stacks, etc.